# How to reduce the background from an H1?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to reduce the background of my H1 font using css.

Here is my css file.

```
.headline h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    background: #fff;

    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
    background-position:
}
```

[image: this is how it is showing up]
i want to achieve this.
[image: what i want to achieve]

Comment: create a fiddle to show your problem

Comment: I don't understand what you want.

Comment: i want to decrease the size of the white background of the font

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `h1` to `display: inline-block`, and it should work!

After that, if you want to center it again, you need to put `text-align: center` in the parent element.